# React.jsx problems with Browserify

Tags: reactjs, browserify

```
var _carouselListJsx = require('./carouselList.jsx');

var _reactRedux = require('react-redux');

var CarouselOuter = (function(_React$Component) {
_inherits(CarouselOuter, _React$Component);

function CarouselOuter(props) {
    _classCallCheck(this, CarouselOuter);

    _React$Component.call(this, props);
    this.state = this.state || {};
    this.state.jsEnabled = false;
}

CarouselOuter.prototype.componentDidMount = function componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        jsEnabled: true
    });
};

CarouselOuter.prototype.render = function render() {
    return _react2['default'].createElement(
        'div',
        null,
        _react2['default'].createElement(
            'ul',
            null,
            this.props.photoData.map(function(data, index) {

                return _react2['default'].createElement(_carouselListJsx.CarouselList, {
                    key: index
                });
            })
        )
    );
};

return CarouselOuter;
})(_react2['default'].Component);
```

I have the above which is the browerified part of my .jsx file.  The file carouselList.jsx is brought in fine as I can console.log this fine, but when CarouselOuter tries to render it via _carouselListJsx.CarouselList it is undefined.

I am not sure what the _carouselListJsx.CarouselList refers to but it is undefined. Below is the CarouselList.jsx file

```
import React from 'react';

class CarouselList extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
          </div>
        );
    }

}

export default CarouselList;
```

Any thoughts/help appreciated.

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the imported files not using _interopRequireDefault, not sure why this is not being done

Comment: Figured it out, somehow I was using the import statement incorrectly.  Small thing but really fazed me.